# ModuleNotFoundError even though Pillw is installed

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm `Python 3.8.2`. I installed `Pillow` to my `venv`. When I run `pip list` I can see that version 9.5.0 is installed but if I attempt to run my application I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "FFL.py", line 9, in 
> from PIL import ImageTk
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Why is this?

Comment: Check in your IDE/Editor which python you are using to execute your application. If it's not matched switch to the venv python.